# По каким правилам ставить или не ставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

У Достоевского есть такой пример: А Петр Петрович, по крайней мере по многим признакам, человек весьма почтенный.

У меня примеры намного проще, но я не знаю по каким правилам (уточнения, дополнения, пояснения или др.) ставить или не ставить запятые или тире.
Я расставил так (скорее всего, неправильно):

1. Иванов, по многим показателям, спортсмен неплохой.
2. По многим показателям Иванов - спортсмен неплохой.
3. Иванов - неплохой спортсмен, по многим показателям.
4. Иванов по многим показателям был неплохим спортсменом.

Это не домашнее задание. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

"А Петр Петрович, по крайней мере по многим признакам, человек весьма почтенный". Здесь вводное слово относится к обособленному обстоятельству.

РЕШЕНИЕ

1) Иванов, по многим показателям, спортсмен неплохой (правильно).

2) По многим показателям Иванов - спортсмен неплохой (нежелательно).

Иванов по мнОгим показателям / спортсмен неплохой.

3) Иванов - неплохой спортсмен, по многим показателям (нежелательно).

Иванов неплохОй спортсмен, причем по многим показателям.

4) Иванов по многим показателям был неплохим спортсменом (нежелательно).

Иванов  был неплохим спортсмЕном /по мнОгим показателям.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Простое предложение строится по принципу тема-рема, предмет-сообщение о предмете. Между ними делается короткая пауза, которая обозначает раздел частей/фраз.

2) "По всем показателям" можно обособить, а можно включить в тему или рему. В последнем случае надо правильно построить структуру предложения с учетом пауз и ударений.

3) Предложение должно читаться, то есть нужно правильно расставить пауз и логические ударения. Тире (и пауза), которое вроде бы нужно ставить по правилам, не всегда вписывается в интонационную схему, поэтому его отсутствие можно списать на разговорный стиль.

4) Предложенные варианты построены по слуху/интонации и по семантике. Возможно, есть и другие варианты.